# Specific FileNotFound Exception

Tags: java, io

I've been trying at this for hours now and I cannot seem to understand why or how I am getting a `FileNotFound` exception.

I am trying to use a file called `rating.txt` that I need to read and write to
My directory looks like this:

[image]

My code is this

```
  public String getRating()
{
    String re = "";
    try {
        FileReader fileReader = new 
     FileReader("app/src/main/files/rating.txt");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        re = bufferedReader.readLine();
        bufferedReader.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("rating file not found while reading");
    }
   return re;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pls check your working directory by using:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

I think your directory start from `app`, so you should change the path to `src/main/files/rating.txt`

Comment: I tried using `src/main/files/rating.txt` and it still said file not found. When i printed out the user directory property it printed a `/`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you're trying to run your code. But as I see, you're using IntelliJ IDEA and in IntelliJ, when you try to run a piece of code, the current working directory of the application being run is your module's output folder. In your case, as you're using gradle, all your classes are being compiled into the `build` folder. So you should first find where your files would be placed under the `build` folder and then change your code so that it tries to lookup the file relative to the `build` folder.

**Important:** When you want to have a sort of a text file in your project, by convention you should put it in the a folder called `resources` beside `java` folder. The `java` plugin automatically looks for such folder and copies its contents to the `build` folder.

So your project structure should be something like this:

```
app
|_ build
|_ src
   |_ java
   |_ resources 
      |_ files <- put your txt file here
```

Then in your code you can read it as this:

```
FileReader fileReader = new 
     FileReader("files/rating.txt");
```

Comment: I added a folder called `resources` next to the java folder, and placed my files in there and it still didn't work.

Here is an image of my directory: https://imgur.com/fqZBeRc

How would i go about changing my relative files to the build folder anyways?

Comment: How do you exactly run the code? Can you take a screenshot of your run configuration on IntelliJ?

Comment: Im not exactly sure what that is because i'm relatively new to programming. I am using Android Studio to develop for android. What information can i provide you with?

Comment: If you're going to run your code on Android, then it's completely different. You can't use normal Java file API to access files. You should read Android documentation. There is a specific convention about the way you should structure your files and folders and the way you can open them. Remember to label your question with `android` so that people get the context of your question and so they can help you better ;)

Comment: Oh, i didnt label it as android because i didnt think there was a specific way needed for android. Thanks for letting me know.